# functional analysis and operator theory

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If the nonlinear operator N defined on R^n into itself is contraction mapping then how to show I+N is onto operator? where I is identity operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $N$ is a strict contraction you can show $I+N$ is surjective by the usual method; linearity doesn't matter.

Fix $x\in\Bbb R^n$. You want to show that there exists $y$ with $$y+Ny=x.$$That's the same as $$x-Ny=y,$$which says $$Ty=y,$$where $$Ty=x-Ny.$$ It's easy to show $T$ is a strict contraction and you're done.